# MySQL MAX() function to compare numeric values in an update?

Tags: sql, mysql

When updating a row, I want to have a built-in check to do some bounds checking.  Most languages have a MAX() function to return the maximum of the arguments passed, but MySQL seems to use MAX() for something else.  For example:

```
UPDATE person SET dollars = MAX(0, dollars-20) WHERE id=1
```

I want to subtract 20 dollars from person id 1, but I don't want dollars to ever be represented by a negative value, so I want a built-in comparison with 0.  Does this work?  Or is there another way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

MySQL supports a function called [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).  It returns the largest value among a list of its arguments.

```
UPDATE person SET dollars = GREATEST(0, dollars-20) WHERE id=1
```

This isn't a standard function in ANSI SQL, so don't count on it being available in other brands of SQL database.  If you need a vendor-independent solution, use the `CASE` syntax suggested by others.  But if all you need to use is MySQL, this function is more concise.

Comment: Corresponding `MIN()` function is called `LEAST()`